# Блоковый список. C++ ошибка в коде

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, struct

Программа использует блоки для хранение массива данных. В самой функции всё сделано по методическим указаниям, но всё равно компилятор ругается на else if строчку функции, когда мы сдвигаем текущий блок вправо

Структуры данных:

```
struct record //запись с данными
{
    float key; //ключ
    vector<int> intData; //должен быть массивом
    vector<char> charData; // должен быть массивом
    float floatData; //инфа
};
struct block //блок
    {
        size_t      cnt;                //кол-во записей в блоке
        record      cells[blockSize];   //ячейки блока
        block* prev = nullptr;     //предыдущий элемент
        block* next = nullptr;     //следующий элемент
    };

struct blockList //список блоков
{
    block* head = nullptr;     //указатель на голову списка
    block* tail = nullptr;     //указатель на хвост списка
};
```

Функция вставки элемента на нулеове место первого блока: (l - блоклист, b - Блок, r - запись)

```
void blockList_add_begin(blockList* l, record* r) 
    {
        if (!l || !r)
            return;

    //Если список пуст (указатель на голову == nullptr)
    if (!l->head) {
        //Создаем новый блок c этой записью и задаем head
        l->head = new block{ 1, *r };
        //выходим
        return;
    }

    //Если сюда попали, значит список не пуст
    //Если блок в начале (head) может вместить данные
    if (l->head->cnt < blockSize) //блок содержит свободные ячейки(т.е.cnt < blockSize), то вставить элемент(возможно, со сдвигом содержимого блока на одну позицию); увеличить счетчик;
    { 
        //сдвигаем блоки на 1, освобождая 0 место
        for (size_t i = l->head->cnt; i > 0; i--) 
        {
            l->head->cells[i] = l->head->cells[i - 1];
        }
        //на освободившееся записываем данные
        l->head->cells[0] = *r;
        //увеличиваем счетчик записей
        l->head->cnt++;
        //выходим
        return;
    }
    else if (l->head->next->cnt < blockSize) //иначе, т.е блок заполнен до конца; если следующий блок содержит свободные ячейки, то сдвинуть содержимое следующего блока на одну позицию вправо, поместить в нулевую позицию последний элемент текущего блока; увеличить счетчик следующего блока; сдвинуть содержимое текущего блока на одну позицию вправо начиная с позиции вставки, разместить новый элемент;
    {
        for (size_t i = l->head->next->cnt; i > 0; i--) 
        {
            l->head->next->cells[i] = l->head->next->cells[i - 1]; //сдвигаем содержимое след. блока на 1 вправо
        }
        l->head->next->cells[0] = l->head->cells[blockSize - 1]; // помещаем в нулевую позицию последний элемент текущего блока
        l->head->next->cnt++; //увеличиваем счетчик следующего блока

        for (size_t j = l->head->cnt; j > 0; j--)
        {
            l->head->cells[j] = l->head->cells[j - 1]; //сдвигаем содержимое текущего блока на 1 вправо
        }
        l->head->cells[0] = *r; // размещаем новый элемент
        
        return;
    }
    else // следующий блок тоже заполнен до конца создать новый блок и вставить его как узел в двусвязном списке, настроив указатели previous и next там, где необходимо. Осуществить сдвиг в старом блоке, хвостовой элемент поместить в нулевой позиции нового блока, добавляемый элемент - в освободившуюся позицию, счетчику нового блока присвоить единицу;
    {
        //Если сюда попали, значит список не пуст и нет мест в head
        //создаем новый блок с записью
        block* p = new block{ 1, *r };
        //связываем блоки
        p->next = l->head;
        l->head = p;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит "компилятор ругается"? Конкретно - какое сообщение об ошибке он выводит?

Comment: Текст ошибки: Чтение недопустимых данных из "l->head->cells":  доступный для чтения объем равен "360" байт, однако считать можно только "j" байт.

Comment: Первое замечание: вместо  vector<char> вполне можно использовать std::string

Comment: size_t cnt не инициализирован и т.д. безобразие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот смотрите:

```
if (l->head->cnt < blockSize)
```

у вас НЕ выполняется. Значит,

```
l->head->cnt >= blockSize
```

Но далее вы делаете

```
    for (size_t j = l->head->cnt; j > 0; j--)
    {
        l->head->cells[j] = l->head->cells[j - 1];
```

Итак, что получается при первой итерации? `l->head->cells[j]` то же, что и `l->head->cells[l->head->cnt]`, т.е. `l->head->cells[blockSize]` (или даже больший индекс). Выход за границы массива? несомненный.

Думаю, компилятор оказался достаточно умным, чтобы это обнаружить...

У меня ощущение, что вы просто при copy-paste забыли дописать `->next`, нет?

Comment: for (int j = blockSize - 1; j > 0; j--)
  {
   l->head->cells[j] = l->head->cells[j - 1];
                }